# Detecting the types of individual enumeration constants

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, c++14, type-deduction

The code below prints `unsigned int` as the underlying type of all the constants inside the `enum Test`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>

struct Test 
{
    enum { a = true, b = 1 };    
};

static_assert(std::is_same<
    std::underlying_type_t<decltype(Test::a)>, 
    std::underlying_type_t<decltype(Test::b)>>::value, ""
);

int main()
{    
    int status;
    auto const& bi = typeid(std::underlying_type_t<decltype(Test::a)>);
    std::cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(bi.name(), 0, 0, &status); // unsigned int
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a51896646520a589). This also happens if `Test` contains two separate `enum`s with `a` and `b` as before.

**Question**: is it possible to detect that `Test::a` is initialized with `bool` and `Test::b` with `int`? Is there any experimental code for this in any of the Reflection Study Group proposals for C++17?

**NOTE**: I know I can work around it by replacing `Test` with

```
struct Test
{
    static constexpr auto a = true;
    static constexpr auto b = 1;
};
```

but I find the `enum` version slightly less verbose in its usage.

Comment: Hm. After the `}` of the enum, the types of all enumerators are the type of the enum. Within the enum, the type of the enumerator is the type of the initializing value [dcl.enum]/5 (if the underlying type is not fixed). Don't know about Reflection.

Comment: @dyp I would be even content with a trick to distinguish `bool` from `int` constants.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos I saw your N4113 proposal today, and it allows to query enum constant *values* but not their initializer *types*. Could you comment on that design decision? There's a bounty from [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24477204/819272) :-)

Comment: I believe this question may be a misnomer since all variables in an enum have the same type. You already answered the titular question when you found the type of a.

Comment: @dyp: That should be the answer, not just a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **not possible** and I consider it very unlikely that it will ever be possible.

The reason is that `a` and `b` are values of the (in your case unnnamed) `enum`. Thus they are, by definition, of the type of the `enum`, meaning: Of the same type. The expressions used to initialize them and *their* respective types are only used to "calculate" the underlying type of the `enum`, not of any individual values.

Considering this fact, I think that even reflection will not help to recover the information as the type of the initializing expression is abstracted away when you look at an `enum`'s value.

What you'd need is an even deeper level of inspection where you'd need to access the expression used to initialize the values. That would mean that compilers will have to store a lot of additional information for every variable, values, etc. (since this would be a general thing not just for `enum`s).

Consider what that means:

- Increased compile times
- Increased memory usage when compiling
- Every value would effectively now have *two* types, the type it is declared as and the type of the expression it was initialized from

The last point is what I would consider the real catastrophe for the language. A value should have a single type, the expression used to initialized the value should not be accessible in any way. This is what abstraction is about, breaking it could lead to all kinds of subtle dependencies and a lot of complexity.

<sub>Disclaimer: This is just my personal opinion, I can't speak for anyone on the committee or in the working groups.</sub>

Comment: Tnx, nice and convincing answer. I think this implies that you cannot easily mix `enum` and `static constexpr auto` in type traits introspection a la Boost.TTI. I wanted to write a macro `TRAIT_STATIC_CONSTANT(name, value)` which generates a trait `template<class T> get_constant_name<T>` that stores both a nested type and value. This should look into `T` for `name` and fall back to `value` if `name` is absent. However, if `name` is an enum constant then `decltype(underlying_type_t<T::name>)` and `decltype(value)` are incompatible. Anyway, using `static constexpr auto` everywhere solves it.

Answer (score 2):

You could differentiate int enum values from non-ints as following:

```
struct Test
{
  enum : short { a = true };
  enum : int   { b = 1    };
  // enum : bool { c = false };
};
```

Unfortunately, VC2010 fails to compile a bool as underlying type, which is probably not considered as an integral type. This might not be an issue if your use case only requires separating ints from non-ints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this is not any more convenient than using `static constexpr auto a = true;` and similarly for the other two.